# What ever happened to #WT?

Tags: c#, java, swt, port, icsharpcode

What ever happed to #WT (SharpWT) by ICSharpCode, a port of SWT from JVM to .NET? I can't find it anywhere. Thanks.

I've tried looking forward it on the net, but cant find it. It would be especially useful to find as I wrote a program in Fantom that uses SWT and Fantom supports both the Java and CLR runtimes.

Answer (score 1):

Dead, it sounds [like](http://osdir.com/ml/gnome.mono.swt.devel/2004-05/msg00002.html)

Comment: Thanks. Know of any good databases of old software that you can download?

Comment: Nvm. I found it here: http://ftp.heanet.ie/disk1/sourceforge/s/project/sh/sharpdevelop/OldFiles/ if anyone else is interested.